# Sharing information between android applications

Tags: android, share, smartphone

In several applications I have downloaded and installed from the Android Market I have found that there is a feature, this feature allows you to share information created by the application to other applications and services.
For example, I can use an application called *Instant Heart Rate* (IHR) that measures my heart rate, and if I click on the "Share" button I can send the image produced by IHR to Facebook, mail, and some other applications as well. This list of applications seems to fill automatically when I install more applications to my mobilephone.

What I want to know is, what is this feature called? I want to add this to my applications, both the sending and the receiving of information (images and texts mostly).

Thank you in advance for response.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is, what is this feature called?

An `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. [Here's an old blog post](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/02/a-call-to-action-action_send-that-is/) of mine describing its use.